# How to dynamically display object properties in a textbox in Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation

Im wondering if there is a way in Indesign CC to get object properties and display them in a text box. In particular the height of a box in pixels.

So, if the height of a box changes from 800px to 1200px another textbox, one that I can keep somewhere else for reference, will update that information as I change the height of the box during the design process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this automatically.  However, Rorohiko made a plug-in/script called [FrameReporter](https://www.rorohiko.com/wordpress/indesign-downloads/framereporter/) that will provide this information for you.

You can try the script for free, see if it works for you, and then purchase it for long-term use.

Answer (score 1):

Try, TYPE menu, text variables then define a new one. Type would be Metadata caption. metadata: dimensions.